# get value of a variable from a python script

Tags: php, python, json, exec

I have a python script that returns a json object. Say, for example i run the following:

```
exec('python /var/www/abc/abc.py');
```

and it returns a json object, how can i assign the `json` object as a variable in a php script.

#### Example python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys 

def main():
    data = {"Fail": 35}
    sys.stdout.write(str(data))

main()
```

#### Example PHP script:

```
<?php

exec("python /home/amyth/Projects/test/variable.py", $output, $v);
echo($output);

?>
```

The above returns an empty Array. Why so ?

I want to call the above script from php using the `exec` method and want to use the json object returned by the python script. How can i achieve this ?

Update:

The above works if i use another shell command, For Example:

```
<?php

exec("ls", $output, $v);
echo($output);

?>
```

Anyone knows the reason ?

Comment: Does the Python script output an object in JSON notation? If so, it's simply `json_decode(exec(...))`. If not, make it output :)

Comment: You'd need to *print* the JSON data, not return it..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Even if I print it returns an empty Array. Check updated question.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: you mean using it with `ls`. Yeah it works for me as well for any system commands but as soon as i switch to running any custom python scripts it returns an empty `Array`

Comment: Actually, I meant with it running your Python script, although mine was in a different location.

Answer (score 2):

If the idea is you'll have a Python script which prints JSON data to standard out, then you're probably looking for [`popen`](http://php.net/popen).

Something like...

```
<?php

$f = popen('python /var/www/abc/abc.py', 'r');
if ($f === false)
{
   echo "popen failed";
   exit 1;
}
$json = fgets($f);
fclose($f);
```

...will grab the output into the `$json` variable.

As for your example Python script, if the idea is you're trying to convert the Python dictionary `{"tests": "35"}` to JSON, and print to standard out, you need to change `loads` to `dumps` and `return` to `print`, so it looks like...

```
import simplejson

def main():
    data = simplejson.dumps({"tests": "35"})
    print data

main()
```

Comment: for this i need to print the data instead of returning, right ?

Comment: still doesn't work. It says `$json` is a Boolean type object.

Comment: Updated answer, but it means that the popen() failed, so either python isn't in your path, it can't find `/var/www/abc/abc.py` or there's an error in your Python script.

Comment: It actually had to do with permissions.

Comment: Ah. That would also explain it. :)